# How to add comas between numbers Excel, Csv

Tags: excel, csv

I have this data of numbers in csv file, pretty lot of them.
[image: example data]

I want to give 1 comas in the first 3 nominals and comas in the first 1 nominals

Example : 10686200000000000 to 106,86200000000000
and this too -6286540000000000 to -6,286540000000000

I get this data from excel and save them into csv, because when save as cannot contain comas in csv I I use number without comas.

How to make it fast so I don't need to add it one by one?

Comment: **because when save as cannot contain comas in csv i i use number without comas.** That is when you save as `CSV Comma Delimited`. Try saving it as `CSV UTF-8 (Comma Delimited)`

Comment: You can also save as `Formatted Text (Space Delimited)` It will save as a `.Prn` file. You can later rename it to `.Txt` if you wish

Comment: It works, thankyou. first i need to increase decimal so 106,895230998306 not displayed as 107. then i save it as **CSV UTF-8 (Comma Delimited)**

Comment: Great. You can feel free to post it as an answer and accept it so that it can help any future visitors who have similar queries :)